# Defining data type using a constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a component that holds a state for a form, but I want this component to be a controller for multiples forms, so I can use the form to create and edit, and it is looking some ugly by now:

formController.js

```
state = { 
  //first form rental
    id: ''
    cost: 0,
    description: '',
    address: ''
  //second form rent
    id:'',
    price:0,
    tenant:'',
    paymentDate:
}
```

So I want to know if a good approach would be if creating an object constructor for each form, this is how I create the state now following an OOP style:

constructors.js:

```
export const Rental = (cod, cost, address, description) => {
    return {
        cod,
        cost,
        address,
        description
    }
}
export const Rent = (cod, price, tenant, paymentDate) => {
    return {
        cod,
        price,
        tenant,
        paymentDate,
    }
}
```

formController.js:

```
state = { 
       newRental: new Rental('', 0, '', ''),
       newRent: new Rent('', 0, '', '')
    }
```

It looks much better to me, this is a good practice to handle custom data types?.

Comment: this is really just opinion.  do whichever makes you happier.  React doesn't care.

Comment: Just curious, why the `new` keyword?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda The new operator, creates an instance a user-defined object type, in this case, creates an instance of the Rental object and assigned it to  newRental.

Comment: That's what constructors are for.